# Unable to add more than one button in Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I use Linear Layout in my code and I want to add buttons in my activity using vertical scrollbar. But I'm not able to add more than one button in android. Drag and drop is not working and also manual xml coding doesn't work either. Please help

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/chco"
    tools:context="com.example.tset.test.Prerequisites">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: what is the real issue you are facing ?

Comment: I'm not able to add buttons in my activity.

Comment: Please check my answer :)

Comment: please check the screenshot..I used "match_parent" for android:width.. I need the buttons to fill the screen .. pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/chco"
tools:context="com.example.tset.test.Prerequisites"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried it. please refer my screenshot above. button doesn't fit on the screen. it's left side aligned

Comment: @Elackya please check you are making it wrap_content, instead use match_parent. like I have used in my answer.

Comment: Thank you .. it worked.. I corrected android:layout_width="wrap_content" under Linear Layout tag and it worked.Thanks

Comment: @Elackya happy to help. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/chco"
    tools:context="com.example.tset.test.Prerequisites">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Traveler Login" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:text="Login" />
                </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/chco"
            tools:context="com.example.tset.test.Prerequisites">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/login_bg"
    tools:context=".activities.LoginActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Login"/> 
            <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/submit1"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Login1"/> 
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```